# not receiving any firebase notifications on 4.4.2 android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have registered my app on firebase console. I am also receiving a firebase Token id/Reg id on all of my testing devices.
I am receiving firebase notifications through api on 7.0.1 one plus 3 android device.
But not receiving any firebase notifications through api on 4.4.2 Q1010i xolo android device.

These are the details of the device and the issue :

**Configurations of my testing device :**

```
OS : Android 4.4.2

Google play services version : 11.5.09
```

► **I have tried both the ways i.e. app in background and app in foreground while testing the notification feature but didnt receive any notification in both the cases.**

```
Device Model : Q10010i XOLO
```

► Tried firebase console alert and received it on the XOLO android device with `os 4.4.2` . But didn't receive notification through api on the same device.

► **Below mentioned is the response of api :**

```
    {"multicast_id":5962490856340262772,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,
"results":[{"message_id":"0:1509517732835898%f684319df9fd7ecd"}]}
```

► **Payload of api :**

```
 {"data":{"title":"Firebase API Alert","is_background":false,"message":"Firebase 
    API Notification Testing","image":"","payload":{"name":"Media Nucleus","product_id":"BFLIX"},
"timestamp":"2017-11-01 07:45:38"}}
```

► **Type of message being sent is : Data**

I am unable to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Check your device internet is connected or not

Comment: yes my device is connected to wifi vch is working fine..